# Use FParsec to parse float or int*float

Tags: f#, fparsec

I've just started out playing around with FParsec, and I'm now trying to parse strings on the following format

```
10*0.5 0.25 0.75 3*0.1 0.9
```

I want 3*0.1, for example, to be expanded into 0.1 0.1 0.1

What I have so far is the following

```
type UserState = unit
type Parser<'t> = Parser<'t, UserState>

let str s : Parser<_> = pstring s

let float_ws : Parser<_> = pfloat .>> spaces

let product = pipe2 pint32 (str "*" >>. float_ws) (fun x y -> List.init x (fun i -> y))
```

The product parser correctly parsers entries on the format `int*float` and expands it into a list of floats. However, I'm having trouble coming up with a solution that allows me to parse either `int*float` or just a float. I would like to do something like

```
many (product <|> float_ws)
```

This will of course not work since the return types of the parsers differ. Any ideas on how to make this work? Is it possible to wrap of modify float_ws such that it returns a list with only one float?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `float_ws` return a `float list` by simply adding a `|>> List.singleton`

```
let float_ws : Parser<_> = pfloat .>> spaces |>> List.singleton
```

`|>>` is just the `map` function, where you apply some function to the result of one parser and receive a new parser of some new type:

```
val (|>>): Parser<'a,'u> -> ('a -> 'b) -> Parser<'b,'u>
```

See: http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.:124::62::62:

---

Also, since `product` parser includes an int parser, it will successfully parse a character from the wrong case, this means the parser state will be changed.  That means you cannot use the `<|>` operator on the first parser directly, you must also add `attempt` so FParsec can return to the original parser state.

```
let combined = many (attempt product <|> float_ws)
```

Comment: Great, thanks, `|>>` is very useful to know about! I do however get an error when combining the two parsers and running it on a test string. My combined parser is `let combined = many (product <|> float_ws_list)` where i have defined `let float_ws_list : Parser<_> = pfloat .>> spaces |>> List.singleton`. The string I test it on is `"3*0.5 0.75"`

Comment: I went back and re-read the documentation for the `<|>` operator and realized that if the first parser changes the parser state, it will fail and not try the second parser. I solved by using _attempt_: `let combined = many (attempt product <|> float_ws_list)`

Comment: @Chepe I was literally just typing that as your comment appeared :)  I've updated the answer to include that info.